# Optimising Finite Differences w/SSE

Tags: optimization, simd, nested-loops

I am wondering if it is possible to use SSE (1,2,3,4,...) to optimise the following loop:

```
// u and v are allocated through new double[size*size]
for (int j = l; j < size-1; ++j)
{
    for (int k = 1; k < size-1; ++k)
    {
        v[j*size + k] = (u[j*size + k-1] + u[j*size + k+1] 
                       + u[(j-1)*size + k]+ u[(j+1)*size + k]) / 4.0;
    }
}
```

The `[j*size + k]` idiom is used to treat the block of memory as if it were a multi-dimensional array.

Sadly the `-ftree-vectorize` flag for GCC (4.5) does not believe that the loop is amenable to SIMD-type optimisation.  (Although saying that I've never seen `-ftree-vectorize` optimise anything but the most trivial of loops.)

While I am aware that there are many other ways to improve the performance of the loop (OpenMP, unrolling, in-place algorithms, etc) I am specifically interested to know if SIMD can be used.  I am perhaps more interested in the general outline of how (if at all) such a loop could be transformed, as opposed to a concrete implementation.

Comment: Did you try `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=n`?  gcc will give you hints about why it did/didn't vectorize.  One to look out for is that without the `restrict` keyword it will assume v can alias u which blocks a lot of SSE (at best it will make two versions in that case and decide at runtime)

Comment: @Ben Jackson - Yep, I used the -verbose option to conclude that it was not vectorising my code.  I did toy with `restrict` (actually `__restrict__` as I'm C++) but it made no difference as GCC was inlining (and determining that `u` and `v` did not overlap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it should be possible, but since (a) you're using doubles, (b) you're doing very little computation relative to I/O, (c) most modern x86-64 CPUs have two FPUs anyway, then you may not get much return on your SIMD coding investment.

Comment: I used doubles mostly out of habit.  I am unsure about it being I/O bound as on my dual-core system with shared L2 I get an almost linear speed-up when using OpenMP.

Comment: @Freddie: the I/O bound comment was in regard to the scalar loop above - you have just 3 FP adds and 1 FP multiply for 4 loads + 1 store - execution time may well be dominated by the latency of the loads and stores, so making the computation faster (e.g. via SIMD) may gain you nothing.

Comment: @Freddie: if your algorithm can use floats rather than doubles without any numerical precision or stability problems then in that case it might be worth considering SIMD (although note the caveat in the above comment re computation v loads/stores).